# Get SSL private key from certicate request text

Tags: https

I created my certificate request using the IIS wizard and then requested and received my SSL certificate from Symantec.

To add the certificate to our load balancer I require the private key.

Foolishly I've deleted the original certificate from the IIS main panel, which means I can't extract the private key using the technique outlined in [What are the steps to recover the private key of an SSL certificate in an IIS environment?](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905)

Given that I have the original request text, is there anyway to get the private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the private key from CSR.

It is on purpose, that Sertificate Signing Request (CSR) only contains the public key, because CSR will be sent to a certificate authority for signing, but private keys are supposed to be kept private, i.e. not sent to anyone.

If you've lost the key, you'll have to generate a new CSR and keep associated the private key in safe place.